# Is there a way to map a host-cached Vulkan buffer to a specific memory location?

Tags: vulkan, memory-mapping

Vulkan is able to import host memory using `VkImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT`. I queried the supported memory types for `VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_HOST_ALLOCATION_BIT_EXT` but the only kind of memory that was available for it was coherent, which does not work for my use case. The memory needs to use explicit invalidations/flushes for performance reasons. So really, I don't want the API to allocate any host-side memory, I just want to tell it the base address that the buffer should upload from/download to. Otherwise I have to use intermediate copies. Using the address returned by vkMapMemory for the host-side work is not desirable for my use-case.

Comment: By "host-cached" you meant "host-backed", or literaly the `CACHED` type in Vulkan?

Comment: @krOoze I guess I'm very new to Vulkan so maybe I'm using the terminology wrong, but basically I want to mirror memory between the CPU and GPU so that I can access it from either without an implicit PCI-e bus transfer. The project I'm using this for emulates a system with unified memory and if every read/write cause a bus transfer then performance goes out the window pretty quickly. So I need to only send data to or from the host GPU when the guest CPU/GPU are accessing overlapping regions.

Comment: @MarshallMohror: "*I want to mirror memory between the CPU and GPU so that I can access it from either without an implicit PCI-e bus transfer.*" But in a discrete GPU, any memory lives across a PCI-e bus from at least *one* of the devices. If the two devices are sharing some memory addresses, and one device sits across a bus from that memory, then *one of the devices* is going to have slower access to that memory. Vulkan lets you pick which one that will be, but you can't have it be "neither" if the GPU is discrete.

Answer (score 1):

If the Vulkan implementation does not allow you to import memory allocations as "CACHED", then you can't *force* it to do so. The API provides the opportunity for the implementation to advertise the ability to import your allocations as "CACHED", but the implementation explicitly refused to do it.

Which probably means that it *can't*. And you can't make the implementation do something it can't do.

So if you have some API that created and manipulates some memory (which cannot use memory provided by someone else), and the Vulkan implementation won't allow reading from that memory unless it is allowed to remove the cached nature of the allocation, and you need CPU caching of that memory, then you're going to have to fall back on `memcpy`.

---

> I want to mirror memory between the CPU and GPU so that I can access it from either without an implicit PCI-e bus transfer.

If the GPU is discrete, that's *impossible*. In a discrete GPU setup, the GPU and the CPU have separate local memory pools, and access to either pool from the other *requires* some form of PCIe transfer operation. Vulkan lets you pick which one is going to have slower access, but one of them *will* have slower access to the memory.

If the GPU is integrated, then typically there is only one memory pool and one memory type for it. That type will be both local and coherent (and probably cached too), which represents fast access from both devices.

Comment: I am not sure how your first paragraph relates to the question. The Q said it wants non-coherent memory, but import of host pointer is allowed only as coherent. Which kinda makes sense to me, because normal heap memory in C\C++ is by nature coherent.

Comment: @krOoze: "*The Q said it wants non-coherent memory*" Re-read the question. The OP said that they want *cached* memory. They want fast CPU access to the memory; whether that also involves "coherent" access or not isn't the point. My point is that the API has the tools to allow an implementation to let you import memory as "cached", so if it doesn't let you do it, that's probably because it can't.

Comment: Only mention of "cached" is in the Q header, and does not seem to relate to the Q content in the way you interpret. Anyway I am gonna ask the asker.

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding what I want. I just want two separate blocks of memory, and I want to choose when to send data between them. I don't want both devices accessing the same block of memory.

Comment: @MarshallMohror: If you want two separate blocks of memory, why did you ask about a feature that is *specifically* about making Vulkan directly access a block of memory you've allocated? Could you restate your question to make it more clear *exactly* the process you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarshallMohror: I guess my confusion is that, if you want two blocks of memory, one owned by the CPU and one owned by the GPU, and you just want to copy between them, Vulkan has very obvious tools to accomplish this task. So it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry but it's not obvious to me. I think I have an idea of how this is supposed to work now though. Should I be allocating memory that lives on the GPU, mapping it, then memcpy'ing to it?

Comment: @MarshallMohror: That's the basic way that it works. However, depending on how you intend to use that data on the GPU, and the memory types the GPU exposes, you may need a second copy from the data you memcpy'd to the correct destination. If you're doing streaming (copying every frame or nearly so) you probably want to have Vulkan use the data directly from the mapped memory if possible. But if you're only uploading infrequently, you'll want to see that it gets to device-local memory.

Answer (score 0):

Whether `VkImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT` or `vkMapMemory` of non-`DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` heap, you will typically get a `COHERENT` memory type.

Because well, the conventional host heap memory from `malloc` in C is naturally coherent (and the CPUs do typically have automatic cache-coherency mechanisms). There is no `cflush()` nor `cinvalidate()` in C.

There is no reason for there being implicit PCI-e transfers when R\W such memory from the Host side. Of course, the dedicated GPU has to read it somehow, so there would be bus transfers when the deviced tries to access the memory. Or you need to have an explicit memory in `DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` heap, and transfer data between the two explicitly via `vkCmdCopy*` to keep them the same.

Actual UMA achitectures could have a non-`COHERENT` memory type. But their memory heap is always advertised as `DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` (even if it is the main memory).